# How to retrieve specific elements from a pandas cell containing a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df
       cars                       places
0   [10, 20, 30, 40]            [0, 0, 0, 3]
1   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]    [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
2   [10, 20]                    [0, 1]
```

I want to get the third column created having only those elements from column `"cars"` that corresponds to the number `0` in the column `places`.
Thus, the desired output is

```
          cars                    places            stolen
0   [10, 20, 30, 40]             [0, 0, 0, 3]       [10, 20, 30]
1   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]     [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5] [10, 20]
2   [10, 20]                     [0, 1]             [10]
```

What is the smoothest way to perform that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the apply function

```
df['stolen'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['cars'][i] for i, j in enumerate(x['places']) if j==0], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                       cars              places        stolen
0          [10, 20, 30, 40]        [0, 0, 0, 3]  [10, 20, 30]
1  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]  [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]      [10, 20]
2                  [10, 20]              [0, 1]          [10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['stolen'] = [[car for car, place in zip(cars, places) if not place] for cars, places in zip(df.cars, df.places)]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                       cars              places        stolen
0          [10, 20, 30, 40]        [0, 0, 0, 3]  [10, 20, 30]
1  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]  [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]      [10, 20]
2                  [10, 20]              [0, 1]          [10]
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['stolen'] = np.where((df['places']==0),df['cars'],'')`

Comment: In my case it returns empty `stolen` column

Comment: More explanation would make it easier for the question asker to understand what you are trying to convey. I would suggest going back an adding additional detail as to why this is the right answer for the question.